# Wireless NAS for media storage and browsing

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, nas

I'd like to purchase a NAS to use for media storage, mostly pictures, as well as for storing IP camera video feeds and occasional time machine (mac) backups. Currently, I have an old 2 drive NAS that I use for this, but the biggest pain point is in browsing photos over AFP or SMB from my Mac - it's basically unusable - photo previews take too long to load. This is my most important use case - being able to browse/manage photos stored on my NAS from my Mac, ideally, wirelessly (my wife doesn't want to have to plug into something to browse photos).

Is this possible? I was thinking a 4 bay NAS with 1 drive dedicated for videos and the other drives for media might be good (photos I'd like in at least RAID 1 since I don't want to lose them). Any hardware options I should consider? Any storage arrangements I should consider or networking?

Comment: You can keep your NAS on the Wired Network, and then as long as the wired network has a wireless access points, as long as you / your wife connects to that same network (over wired, or wireless) - both of you can access the files on the NAS. Depends on how old your NAS is (and the HDD inside the NAS, or even what RAID is used) - that could be the slow-point of why your browsing is slow over the NAS.

Comment: @Darius - The NAS I run now is a Synology DS210j - 800mhz, 128MB RAM, in RAID 0 configuration. It receives about ~70KB constant writes from my 2 IP cameras, and those same drives (in RAID 0) are used for serving photos. I was thinking of upgrading to a newer beefier 4 bay NAS, but before I do I want to make sure this will even solve my problem. How can I determine if the bottleneck is my network or NAS?

Comment: Create a set of files (of fixed size / number of files) and use it as your test. Assuming there are no other network activity, transfer the files across over wifi / wired from your mac to your wife's mac and note down the transfer speed. Then do the same from your mac to your NAS. Also take note what do you use to transfer (FTP, SMB, or AFP as they may make a difference). Upgrading the NAS may not be necessary, but getting new HDD may improve if your HDD is old and maybe dying.

Comment: Also do NOT use RAID0. RAID0 is speed and no redundancy. If you want to ensure the RAID set survives, use RAID1 (mirroring). I personally use the SHR from Synology with 1 disk redundancy (I got DS413 4-bay personally).

Comment: @Darius - My mistake, I'm using RAID 1. Thanks for the heads up :) Performing test....

Comment: @Darius - A quick file copy test shows ~350KBs over wireless from the NAS to a Mac and 5MBs wired. Similarly, a wireless speedtest.net test shows ~12mb/s down whereas wired it's around 98mb/s (probably maxing out my 100mb router). So now I wonder if browsing photos over wireless is even doable...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55721/discussion-between-darius-and-josh-stone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest Synology (DS416, DS216).
They are stable and, i hope, affordable.
Use wired connection from your NAS to the Router/Switch. Your wife will still be able to connect over WLAN to the device (tru the existing AP). WLAN is always slower.

- Try to keep your folders small (not 1000 photos in one folder).
- DON'T do Raid 5. Raid 1 is fine on performance.

Comment: ps: the ds1515 is even better, but also expensive. ps2: wd red hdd's are superb. good in performance and made to use 24/7. if you dont like the noise when read/write from/to the hdds and the noise of hdd vibration, go for wd red PRO, the have less noise and vibration, if you go for more than 4 hdd, you need wd red pro to stay stable. i always buy nas without hdd and deploy them by myself, so i know exactly what i have, and what i have to buy when a drive fail. kind regards